# hive expression not in group by key size

Tags: hadoop, hive

My table Schema is (State string,City String,Size int)

Here is my input data

```
Karnataka,Bangalore,200
Karnataka,Mysore,50
Karnataka,Bellary,100
Karnataka,Mangalore,10
Andhra pradesh,Chittoor, 25
Andhra pradesh,nellore, 15
Andhra pradesh,guntur, 20
Andhra pradesh,tirupathi, 30
Andhra pradesh,vizag, 35
Andhra pradesh,kadapa, 45
```

I want to retrieve top 2 city's of the state along with size, I want the output as below.

```
(Andhra pradesh,{(35),(30)},{(vizag),(tirupathi)})
(Karnataka,{(200),(100)},{(Bangalore),(Bellary)})
```

I have written the query as follow but I am getting error as expression not in group by size, plz help me out.

```
select * from statefile groyp by state,city order by size limit 2;
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `row_number()`:

```
select sf.*
from (select sf.*,
             row_number() over (partition by state order by size desc) as seqnum
      from statefile sf
     ) sf
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: It will work if you just change partition by state instead of city. Just look at the column names, I have edited the question.